# I want to run more than 1 command with the FOR /F

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to make a script to:
send a request to an url, then append (>>) the %%a variable i set in the FOR /F command IF i get a certain response from the command i run with FOR /F.
I tried with 2 scripts that are the followings:

```
FOR /F %%a in (usernames.txt) do (
IF "curl -k -d name=%%a https://club.pokemon.com/api/signup/verify-username" EQU "{"valid":true,"suggestions":[],"inuse":false}" %%a >> usernames1.txt
```

and

```
set /p VAR = < tmpFile
FOR /F %%a in (usernames.txt) do (
curl -k -d name=%%a https://club.pokemon.com/api/signup/verify-username 
> tmpFile
IF VAR={"valid":true,"suggestions":[],"inuse":false}
%%a >> usernames1.txt)
```

EDIT: good enough with that script, thanks guys. but i've got another thing: can i add more than 1 variable to the script? I mean a variable like %%a, that takes every line from another txt file

Comment: There is no closing `)` in your first `for /F` loop...

Comment: In addition to JFF's solution below (`!var!` accessing the dynamic value of VAR in `delayedexpansion` mode) beware of `set /p VAR = < tmpFile` since this sets a variable named "VAR[space]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you set `VAR` once, whereas your temporary file does not exist. Then you test with = instead of == and without the `!` chars.

And don't put too many spaces like if you were using a real shell like bash :)

As Magoo noted, I also had to fix `set /p VAR = < tmpFile` to remove the extra spaces. Batch has a tendency to take them literaly.

(another example: `echo foo > file`: `file` now contains `"foo "`.

(needless to say that without `enabledelayedexpansion` it wouldn't work either because lots of things happen inside the `FOR` loop)

The fixed code (also had to protect the test string with extra quotes or it wouldn't work):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

del usernames1.txt >NUL 2>NUL
FOR /F %%a in (usernames.txt) do (
curl -k -d name=%%a https://club.pokemon.com/api/signup/verify-username > tmpFile 2>NUL
set /p VAR=<tmpFile
IF "!VAR!"=="{"valid":true,"suggestions":[],"inuse":false}" echo %%a >> usernames1.txt
)
```

I tested it with a random list of user names and changing `"valid":true` by `"valid":false` and the names were issued.